# PHPMailer - how to test emails in xampp localhost wordpress installation

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, phpmailer

I need to do some test for email sending in wordpress. I've noticed that I can only use mailtodisk utility but it will only work with the build PHP `mail()` function and not with `wp_mail()`. Since I have a pdf file to attach, is there any solution I can use to achive my scope?

At the moment I have the needing to send an email to a customer that will input his address in a form and will have a specific subject and message body, and another to some stores with different email and different message and subject, the only common thing is the attached file.

Any suggestion? I've read that I can use php mailer that is built in in wordpress, but how I make it works correctly?

Comment: Check [this Stackexchange post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/344009/how-to-use-phpmailer-in-a-function-in-wordpress) please

Comment: As always, the first place you look should be [the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-PHPMailer-in-WordPress).

Comment: @Synchro I've read about the filter and tried to implement it inside my plugin but not worked as expected

Comment: You need to define "not worked", in detail.

Comment: @Synchro when I've added the filter into the plugin costructor using `add_action` the settings are ignored. I've tried to use mailgun for smtp params

Comment: Check that the function is actually being called – put in a noisy `var_dump` or `die` call to make sure your code is actually being run. After that, trace what it's doing, and perhaps check that other plugins are not trying to do something similar that overrides your code.